# Chebyshev polynomial generalization for non-integer degrees

Tags: trigonometry, chebyshev-polynomials

I am trying to generalize the Chebyshev polynomials (especially of first kind) for non-integer degree.
The properties I would like to keep is 
$$2 T_m(x) T_n(x) = T_{m+n}(x) + T_{|m-n|}(x)$$
and
$$T_m(\cos(x))=\cos(mx)$$
So to be more specific generalization of the $T_r(x)$ for non integer $r$ values. 
I have found a document about the half degree polynomials:
[Pseudo-Chebishev Polynomial](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329263170_Complex_Spirals_and_Pseudo-Chebyshev_Polynomials_of_Fractional_Degree/link/5bff5c0445851523d1532e02/download)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want $T_m(\cos(x)) = \cos(mx)$, you might as well simply define
$$ T_m(z) = \cos(m \arccos(z))$$
either as a multivalued function, or use a particular branch of arccos.

EDIT: With $\arccos(z)=t$, note that you do have
$$ 2 T_m(z)  T_n(z) = 2\cos(m t) \cos(nt) = \cos((m-n)t) + \cos((m+n)t)
= T_{m-n}(z) + T_{m+n}(z) $$
And of course $T_{m-n} = T_{n-m}$.  But it's not $T_{|m-n|}$ if $m-n$ is complex.

Comment: OK. This is some kind of obvious but not sure if this keeps the $2 T_m(x) T_n(x) = T_{m+n}(x) + T_{|m-n|}(x)$. And if so is there any series representing this.

Comment: Probably some of those relations are strongly depend on degree being integer.

Comment: Thanks. And is there any paper about this ?